# JPA @PrePersist in test environment

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dao

I have `GenericEntity` class with `@PrePersist` method `onCreate()` which sets timestamp just before saving entity to a DB. It works well but I am facing the problem when I try to test my DAO classes. `@PrePersist` overwrites explicitly set `created` field value when saving entity. How to make @PrePersist optional in the test environment so I could set `created` field value explicitly?

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
    private Date created;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        created = new Date();
    }

    /*
     * Used for tests
     */
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }
}
```

Comment: User EntityListeners as an interceptor for your callback:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html

Comment: I have 2 persistence units in persistence.xml. How to configure them to use different EntityListeners for GenericEntity class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give access to set created value (by setter) you shouldn't overwrite this value in `@PrePersist` method. I think the easiest way to solve the problem is simple null-check:

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    if (created == null) {
        created = new Date();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just == instead of !=

Comment: Yep, my mistake :)